# Responsive grid layout with fixed header, footer and scrollable content

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to create 2 column full height design by using flexbox. When I add scrolling to whole middle part then I have a strange behavior. It seems that flex-grow/stretch doesn't grow/stretch other items if parent container has a scrollbar.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p96qbesa/). Code also given below:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;    
}
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    
    width: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}

#container header {
    background-color: gray;
}
#container section {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 0px;
}
#container footer {
    background-color: gray;
}
aside {
  width : 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
article{
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
article > div{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#content {
  display:flex;   
}
```

```html
<section id="container" >
<header id="header" >This is a header</header>
<section id="content">
  <aside>
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
    test<br />
  </aside>
  <article id="article" >
    <div>               
      This is the content that
      <br />
      With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      This is the content that
      <br />
      With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      <br />
      This is the content that
      <br />
      With a lot of lines.
      <br />
      <br />
      This is the content that
      <br />
      With a lot of lines.
      <br />
    </div>
    <footer id="footer" >This is a page footer</footer>      
  </article>
</section>
<footer id="footer" >This is a footer</footer>
</section>
```

Basically i'm trying to cover 2 scenarios. It works fine if i don't need to scroll but once i have a scroll the items doesn't stretch correctly:

[image: 1. Main content 'smaller' than left]

[image: 2. Main content 'bigger' than left]

Answer (score 1):

To make this layout work in latest Firefox & Chorme as of today (revising this answer from 2016), I made the following changes:

1. Added `margin: 0` to `body` to allow the `container` to flex to the viewport height.
2. Wrap you the contents on `#content` element in another `section` and make it a *column* flexbox.
3. Make the inner `section`a full-height flexbox and give `min-height: max-content` and `flex: 1`.

See demo below:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0; /* ADDED */
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

#container header {
  background-color: gray;
}

#container > section { /* ADDED > selector */
  display: flex; /* ADDED */
  flex-direction: column; /* ADDED */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 0px;
}

#container > section > section{ /* ADDED */
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: max-content; /* fixes chrome */
  flex: 1; /* fixes firefox */
}

#container footer {
  background-color: gray;
}

aside {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: content;
}

article {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

article>div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <header id="header">This is a header</header>
  <section id="content">
    <section>
      <aside>
        test<br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br /> test
        <br />
      </aside>
      <article id="article">
        <div>
          This is the content that
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br /> This is the content that
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br />
          <br /> This is the content that
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br />
          <br /> This is the content that
          <br /> With a lot of lines.
          <br />
        </div>
        <footer id="footer">This is a page footer</footer>
      </article>
    </section>
  </section>
  <footer id="footer">This is a footer</footer>
</section>
```

The above solution is *hacky* at best and shows us why a flexbox is *weak* in 2D layouts. The answer is it is just not designed for it. But [**`CSS Grids`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) are - see how easily everything falls into place:

1. Make `#container` a full viewport high *grid* element.
2. Make the *middle* `section` a *grid* container with `grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr` along with *overflow* property and you are almost done.

See demo below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
  display: grid;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

header, footer {
  background-color: gray;
}

#container section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

aside {
  background-color: blue;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

article > div {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="container">
  <header id="header">This is a header</header>
  <section id="content">
    <aside>
      test<br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br /> test
      <br />
    </aside>
    <article id="article">
      <div>
        This is the content that
        <br /> With a lot of lines.
        <br /> With a lot of lines.
        <br /> This is the content that
        <br /> With a lot of lines.
        <br />
        <br /> This is the content that
        <br /> With a lot of lines.
        <br />
        <br /> This is the content that
        <br /> With a lot of lines.
        <br />
      </div>
      <footer id="footer">This is a page footer</footer>
    </article>
  </section>
  <footer id="footer">This is a footer</footer>
</section>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. If i remove height from container then i have one big scroll. I want add scroll only to the middle part and keep header and the common footer statick

Comment: @Vi_Ros have edited the answer... please check and let me know if this is what you needed. Thanks!

Comment: Now i have 2 separate scrollbars for left and right parts. But i'm trying to reach one scrollbar for both blocks. I've attached the image what i'm trying to fix.

Comment: @Vi_Ros have edited the answer... Check it out now if it works and let me know... :)

Comment: Now it works exactly as in my example. Please try your changes yourself and try to scroll down.

Comment: Well, it works for me in chrome... could you please check?

Comment: It doesn't work for me even in chrome. Try run your code snippet and scroll down you will see exactly the same behavior that i'm trying to fix. see screenshot in description

Comment: @Vi_Ros sorry there... I had checked in my desktop chrome and it was working... just checked in firefox and chrome in my office system (which had latest chrome) and was not working! Will look for a solution later and let you know...

Comment: @Vi_Ros well, I tried... I don't think there is a solution for this with pure CSS using flexbox without using the less supported `min-content` property... :( I'll update here if I get any more ideas....

Comment: Yesterday i played with min-content and it perfectly does what i need. But min-content not supported in many browsers, so i need to find an alternative solution.