# CSS Flexbox or CSS Grid for Header, Sticky Footer and Vertically Aligned Middle Content all together?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

I have a requirement on which we have Header, Middle Section and Footer.

Header and Footer height can be more or less depending on the various screen sizes and content within them.

Footer will be sticky, at the end of the screen if the page doesn't contain scroll and should not overlap over the middle content if scrolling occurs for small screens. Typical sticker footer behavior.

Middle section contains two columns. And Each column content should be vertically center aligned.

Please refer below screenshot for reference what

Note: I can use normal sticky footer and CALC to adjust the height of the main content, but it will not be dynamic. I don't want to use javascript to do all mathematics on DOMContentLoaded and window resize.

[image]

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454280/responsive-grid-layout-with-fixed-header-footer-and-scrollable-content/39454511#39454511) might help you get started...

Comment: Thanks, @kukkuz, but your suggested answer is not fit for the given scenario.

Comment: add your code. thanks

Comment: Do you want the footer to be visible all the times? and you don't want the footer to overlap the body content??

Comment: Though the idea is nice much similar to mobile application, but nonetheless we have no code here and unless you expect someone to do it entirely for you, probably stackoverflow is not the right place.

Comment: @YourPalNurav, I don't want the footer to be visible all the times. It should behave as normal sticky footer, if page have less content then window height, Footer should be sticky at the bottom of the screen, else it should be after all content of the page.

Comment: @vssadineni, sometimes it is better to write/think as our own way instead of editing someone's code or thinking like someone else. This requirement is some tricky and it can have few approaches to achive the goal, so I didn't share any code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My approach uses a bunch of flexboxes and keeps things simple.

- `.container` is a columnar flexbox
- `main` takes up the most available space
- `header`, `footer` take only the space they need (dynamic)
- `main` is also a flexbox, but in the row direction to house the left and right panels
- the panels, too, are flexbox containers, centering their content horizontally and vertically
- You might want to view the demo in 'Full page' mode, or in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v63rcp70/2/)

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.panel1,
.panel2 {
  background-color: brown;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.panel-content {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 3em;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>Header</header>
  <main>
    <div class="panel1">
      <div class="panel-content">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel2">
      <div class="panel-content">
        Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>Sticky Footer</footer>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v63rcp70/2/)